# Get URL # fragment XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Im building a chrome extension that will allow a user to select Facebook posts and send them to a server.

I have an XMLHTTPRequest that i am sending to Facebook in order to receive an access token as follows:

```
function GetToken() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token");
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xhr.close;
    }
}
```

}

The XMLhttpRequest sent to the server is successful and i do receive an access token in response but i dont know how to get access to it.

If i have the console window open on chrome and select the network tab, i can see the request being sent, and the response being received (With the access token) but its received as a URL fragment and i don't have a clue how to get access to it.

GetToken function is executed in a content script if that makes a difference.

EDIT:

xhr.responseText is as follows

Success 
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.setTimeout(function() {window.history.replaceState && window.history.replaceState({}, "", "blank.html#*=*");},500);

xhr.responseXML is as follows

null

Comment: Can you show us response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, you cannot gain access to the URL fragment of a xmlhttprequest response.

so what i have done instead is when my extension button is clicked a new tab is opened with below URL and then a content script is executed immediately in order to get the URL fragment before it is deleted.

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
var Token_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token";
    chrome.tabs.create({ "url": Token_url, "index": tab.tabId });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.tabId, { file: 'FbToken.js', runAt: 'document_start' });
});
```

FbToken.js is a simple file that contains:

```
var AccessToken = window.location.hash;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.greeting == "AccessToken")
sendResponse({ Token: AccessToken });
});
```

Comment: You are right. 

"If the URL is returned, any URL fragment present in the URL will be stripped away. The value of responseURL will be the final URL obtained after any redirects."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your response, executing a console.log(xhr.response, xhr.responseText) and post it here (modifying accordingly with some dummy data)? I think you need to manipulate some strings to get the value you need.

Comment: i dont recieve the access token through either of these responses, but i can see the access token in the developer window network tab.